# What's the meaning of "latching his case"?

Tags: vocabulary

> “I’m not sure that I can accept all your theories.”
>   Pescatelli smiled, as though he’d lured Augustinto a trap.
>   “That’s why I need Kirk to shoot the ghosts,” he said, “I need to shore up the points in the  book.  I gave him a list of every ghost I knew of in town.”
>   Idiot, August thought, Pescatelli was an idiot.  But he nodded, content to let Pescatelli  think he won a valuable hill in their war of wills.
>   “As you say,” he said, **latching his case**.

What's the meaning of this "latching his case". I don't think that's an idiom because I can't find it anywhere on the Internet.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks to me like August has a briefcase which he has opened earlier in the conversation, perhaps to withdraw some papers. Now, as he prepares to leave, he latches the case: closes the latches on the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an idiom. The character apparently has a bag or briefcase he is fastening shut. This act also implies that August is about to leave.

Comment: Thanks! I thought he was saying case like a matter, I didn't realise it was an actual case.